# TypeError: Cannot Set property '0' of undefined in React. Once I change code I get error code: 5 In the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localhost

I am trying to build up a calendar for my internship by following a tutorial where the code is not present. The local host is throwing me the error mentioned in the question title and showed in the picture in attachment. I also wrote here below the code of the Generate Date Grid function for my calendar component and someone told me that It looks that I am creating a two-dimensional array and then trying to assign values to it as if it were three-dimensional. So when populating that first week it should be `dateGrid[0][i] = …` but as soon as I do it the server runs: [image]

I have no clue where the error may lay and either how to solve it. So any inputs or clues would be really really appreciated.

[image]

This is My generate grid function

```
    import { DATE, DAYSINMONTH, DAYSINWEEK, MONTHSINYEAR, WEEKSINYEAR } from "./constantsCalendar";

export const checkLeapYear = (year) => {
  return year % 100 === 0 ? year % 400 === 0 : year % 400 === 0;
};

export const getMonthsDaysInYear = (year) => {
  return [
    31,
    checkLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28,
    31,
    30,
    31,
    30,
    31,
    31,
    30,
    31,
    30,
    31,
  ];
};

// Zeller's rule: finding the day of a particular date in the calendar in the history
const calcFirstDayofYear = (y, M = 0, k = 1) => {
  const m = ((M + 10) % 12) + 1;
  const D = (y % 100) - (m > 10 ? 1 : 0);
  const C = Math.floor(y / 100);
  const F =
    k +
    Math.floor((13 * m - 1) / 5) +
    D +
    Math.floor(D / 4) +
    Math.floor(C / 4) -
    2 * C;
  const T = F > 0 ? F : (F - (Math.floor(F) + 2) * 7) % 7;
  return T % 7;
};

export const generateDateGrid = () => {
  // 54 rows, weeks in a year that will be filled by the second function
  const dateGrid = Array.from({ length: WEEKSINYEAR }, (_) =>
    // 7 columns, days in a week
    Array.from({ length: DAYSINWEEK }, (_) => [1])
  );

  const startDayOfTheYear = calcFirstDayofYear(DATE.getFullYear());

  // To populate the first week of the grid
  for (let i = 0; 1 < startDayOfTheYear; i++) {
    dateGrid[0][i][0] = DAYSINMONTH[11] - (startDayOfTheYear - 1) + i;
  }

  let weekValue = 0, k = startDayOfTheYear;
  for(let i = 0; i < MONTHSINYEAR; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < DAYSINMONTH[i]; j++) {
      dateGrid[weekValue][k][0] = j+1;
      k++;
      if(k === DAYSINWEEK) {
        k = 0;
        weekValue++
      }
    }
  }

  // To populate the last row of the date grid
  for(let i = k; i < DAYSINWEEK; i++) {
    dateGrid[weekValue][i][0] = i - k + 1;
  };
  return dateGrid;
};
```

This is my React Calendar Component where the generateFunction is used:

```
    import { DAYSINWEEK, WEEKSINYEAR } from "../../utils/constantsCalendar";
import { generateDateGrid } from "../../utils/dateutils";
import DateComponent from "./date";
import MonthComponent from "./month";
import styled from "styled-components";

const CalendarComponent = () => {
  const dateGrid = generateDateGrid();

  const firstDayInMonth = [];
  const weekRowValue = [];

  //from 0 to 54
  for (let weekIndex = 0; weekIndex < WEEKSINYEAR; weekIndex++) {
    let weekRow = [];
    // from 0 to 7
    for (let dayIndex = 0; dayIndex < DAYSINWEEK; dayIndex++) {
      if (dateGrid[weekIndex][dayIndex][0] === 1) {
        firstDayInMonth.push(weekIndex);
      }
      weekRow.push(
        <DateComponent
          value={[dateGrid][weekIndex][dayIndex][0]}
          day={dayIndex}
          month={firstDayInMonth.length}
        />
      );
    }
    weekRowValue.push(<Week>{weekRow}</Week>);
  }

  let currentMonth = 1,
    monthRow = [];

  const monthRowFunction = Array(WEEKSINYEAR)
    .fill(1)
    .map((val, index) => {
      if (index && index === firstDayInMonth[currentMonth]) {
        const monthValue = (
          <MonthComponent mid={currentMonth - 1}>{monthRow}</MonthComponent>
        );
        currentMonth++;
        monthRow = [weekRowValue[index]];
        return monthValue;
      } else {
        monthRow.push(weekRowValue[index]);
      }
    });
  return monthRowFunction;
};

// STYLES
const Week = styled.div`
display: flex;
scroll-snap-align: start;
`;

export default CalendarComponent;
```

Comment: first try to console `dateGrid`. see if the values are coming in 2D array. Error is basically saying you don't have value dateGrid[0][i]

Comment: This condition is also highly suspicious: `for (let i = 0; 1 < startDayOfTheYear; i++) {`. The `1` should be likely `i`.

Comment: thanks @ShankarNanda I tried to console log it but nothing shows off.. Do you know where should I console log it? Also I noticed that the terminal says: Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of the arrow function. In the Calendar code, but there is

Comment: Thanks a lot @Halcyon I fixed that problem and now i got this one:)

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in the CalendarComponent
src/components/calendar/calendar.js:24
  
 weekRow.push(<DateComponent> value={[dateGrid][weekIndex][dayIndex][0]} day={dayIndex}
 month={firstDayInMonth.length}
 />

Comment: Solved it, there was in           value={dateGrid[weekIndex][dayIndex][0]}
a  [ before dateGrid:)

all good, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, there was in calendar: value={dateGrid[weekIndex][dayIndex][0]}
a "[" before dateGrid... also as mentioned by @Halcyon in the DateGrid function, for (let i = 0; 1 < startDayOfTheYear; i++) {...
There was a 1 instead of i